# WinForms Icon on taskbar not changing after installation

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, icons

I created simple chat app using WinForma in VS for me and my girlfriend, when I'm debugging app, everything works ok - taskbar icon is changing on event, but after deployment and installation icon is static - taken from application->resource settings, which I set to first option (Icon and Manifest).

1. All icons are in .resx file
2. Form.Icon is set from Proprties.Resources.XXX
3. Event which fires tasbar icon change is in another task, so I'm changing it with `Invoke(new Action(() => Icon = Properties.Resources.YYY));`

I assume that App taskbar icon is compiled in executable and could not be easily changed. So is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Application icon (as shown in Explorer when you browse the exe; is not the same thing as a Form's icon (set, for its default value, in the designer). Could you update the Q to be clear about which icon you are asking?

Comment: oh sorry, now it's correct.